# Sumup value for every 5 mins grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

As, I was unable to generate the query to get the resultset of every 5 mins of data between the two dates and group it for the tags

Earlier, I have posted in the below link but now the requirement has changed
[Sum up data for every 30 mins between two different datetimes - Oracle SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75154527/sum-up-data-for-every-30-mins-between-two-different-datetimes-oracle-sql-query/75182379#75182379)

There is a requirement where I need to apply the formula's of every times of arrival data.
Im unable to proceed with the grouping. To explain it more ellaborately

Below is the data arrival (Reading-- Table)

| RDNG_DT | TAG | ST_TIME | END_TM | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-Jan-23 | ALB | 10-Jan-23 | 10-Jan-23 | 2 |
| 10-Jan-23 | ALB | 10-Jan-23 | 10-Jan-23 | 4 |
| 10-Jan-23 | BCD | 10-Jan-23 | 10-Jan-23 | 6 |
| 10-Jan-23 | BCD | 10-Jan-23 | 10-Jan-23 | 8 |
| 10-Jan-23 | BAT | 10-Jan-23 | 10-Jan-23 | 2 |
| 10-Jan-23 | BAT | 10-Jan-23 | 10-Jan-23 | 8 |

For the clarification, I used the `to_CHAR(START_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') AS START_TIME,to_CHAR(END_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') AS START_TIME`

| RDNG_DT | TAG | ST_TIME | END_TM | VALUE** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-Jan-23 | ALB | 10-JAN-23 12.00.00.000000000 AM | 10-JAN-23 12.00.05.000000000 AM | 2 |
| 10-Jan-23 | ALB | 10-JAN-23 12.05.00.000000000 AM | 10-JAN-23 12.10.00.000000000 AM | 4 |
| 10-Jan-23 | BCD | 10-JAN-23 12.00.00.000000000 AM | 10-JAN-23 12.00.05.000000000 AM | 6 |
| 10-Jan-23 | BCD | 10-JAN-23 12.05.00.000000000 AM | 10-JAN-23 12.10.00.000000000 AM | 8 |
| 10-Jan-23 | BAT | 10-JAN-23 12.00.00.000000000 AM | 10-JAN-23 12.00.05.000000000 AM | 2 |
| 10-Jan-23 | BAT | 10-JAN-23 12.05.00.000000000 AM | 10-JAN-23 12.10.00.000000000 AM | 8 |

Now, need the grouping of every 5 mins of tags as below .

| RDNG_DT | TAG | ST_TIME | END_TM | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-Jan-23 | ALB | 10-JAN-23 12.00.00.000000000 AM | 10-JAN-23 12.00.05.000000000 AM | 2 |
| 10-Jan-23 | BCD | 10-JAN-23 12.00.00.000000000 AM | 10-JAN-23 12.00.05.000000000 AM | 4 |
| 10-Jan-23 | BAT | 10-JAN-23 12.00.00.000000000 AM | 10-JAN-23 12.00.05.000000000 AM | 2 |
| 10-Jan-23 | ALB | 10-JAN-23 12.05.00.000000000 AM | 10-JAN-23 12.10.00.000000000 AM | 4 |
| 10-Jan-23 | BCD | 10-JAN-23 12.05.00.000000000 AM | 10-JAN-23 12.10.00.000000000 AM | 8 |
| 10-Jan-23 | BAT | 10-JAN-23 12.05.00.000000000 AM | 10-JAN-23 12.10.00.000000000 AM | 8 |

Based on the above table, the new column must apply the formula for the fist set of data of every 5 mins

New colum RST: `Case when ALB.value + BCD.value + BAT.value > 0 THEN ALB.value + BCD.value + BAT.value ELSE 0  END AS 'AFC'`

As a result, grouping occurs for every 5 mins for the tags availability and need to apply the formula.
The final resultset looks like as below

| TAG | ST_TIME | END_TM | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RST | JAN-23 12.00.00.000000000 AM | JAN-23 12.00.05.000000000 AM | 8 |
|  | JAN-23 12.05.00.000000000 AM | JAN-23 12.10.00.000000000 AM | 20 |

I used the below query

```
WITH TST AS
  (
  SELECT 
      RDNG_DT,
       TAG,
       cast(ST_TIME as timestamp),
       cast(END_TM as timestamp),
       VALUE      
      FLOOR((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM cast(start_time as timestamp)) * 60 + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM cast(start_time as timestamp)))/30) AS FL
      
        FROM  Reading 
    WHERE TAG IN ('ALB','BCD','BAT') AND RDNG_DT = '10-JAN-23')
    
    SELECT  RDNG_DT,TAG,RDNG,st_time,ed_time 
    FROM TST
    group by TAG,RDNG,st_time,ed_time
```

Comment: Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can recreate the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Lastly, don't post any images as they cant be cut and pasted.

Answer (score 0):

try using grouping sets

```
select 
      decode(grouping(nro_carga),1, item.descr, 'Total da carga ' ) descr
    , decode(grouping(cd_item),1,nro_carga, cd_item) id
    , sum(qtde_item) qtde

  from tbl1 

  inner join tbl2
    on 1 = 1

where condition = condition

group by
   grouping sets 
   (  
      nro_carga 
    , ( cd_item, item.descr )
   ), 
   ()
order by cd_item
      ,item.descr
      , nro_carga;
```

Answer (score 0):

Youu dont need timestamp to work with hours and minutes, you need date datatype as it contains date and time. Lets take your first table (reading table) as sample data and make dates of DATE datatype (if they aren't already):

```sql
WITH
    tbl (RDNG_DT, TAG, ST_TIME, END_TIME, A_VALUE) AS
        (
            Select To_Date('10-JAN-23', 'dd-MON-yy'), 'ALB', To_Date('10-JAN-23 12:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), To_Date('10-JAN-23 12:05', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 2 From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('10-JAN-23', 'dd-MON-yy'), 'ALB', To_Date('10-JAN-23 12:05', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), To_Date('10-JAN-23 12:10', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 4 From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('10-JAN-23', 'dd-MON-yy'), 'BCD', To_Date('10-JAN-23 12:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), To_Date('10-JAN-23 12:05', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 6 From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('10-JAN-23', 'dd-MON-yy'), 'BCD', To_Date('10-JAN-23 12:05', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), To_Date('10-JAN-23 12:10', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 8 From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('10-JAN-23', 'dd-MON-yy'), 'BAT', To_Date('10-JAN-23 12:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), To_Date('10-JAN-23 12:05', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 2 From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('10-JAN-23', 'dd-MON-yy'), 'BAT', To_Date('10-JAN-23 12:05', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), To_Date('10-JAN-23 12:10', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi'), 8 From Dual 
    )
```

Having dates as dates - you can try the below code to do the TAGs checking, VALUE summing, grouping and where filtering as you need. Here is the SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    TAG, RDNG_DT, ST_TIME, END_TIME, Sum(TAG_VALUES) "TAG_VALUES"
FROM
    (   Select
            'RST' "TAG",
            RDNG_DT,
            LPAD(FLOOR(  ( (ST_TIME - TRUNC(ST_TIME, 'dd')) * 24 * 60 ) / 60 ), 2, '0') || ':' ||                                                     
            LPAD( ( (ST_TIME - TRUNC(ST_TIME, 'dd')) * 24 * 60 ) - (FLOOR(  ( (ST_TIME - TRUNC(ST_TIME, 'dd')) * 24 * 60 ) / 60  ) )  * 60, 2, '0') "ST_TIME",
            --
            LPAD(FLOOR(  ( (END_TIME - TRUNC(END_TIME, 'dd')) * 24 * 60 ) / 60 ), 2, '0') || ':' ||
            LPAD( ( (END_TIME - TRUNC(END_TIME, 'dd')) * 24 * 60 ) - (FLOOR(  ( (END_TIME - TRUNC(END_TIME, 'dd')) * 24 * 60 ) / 60  ) )  * 60, 2, '0') "END_TIME",
            --
            CASE WHEN TAG IN('ALB', 'BCD', 'BAT') THEN A_VALUE ELSE 0 END "TAG_VALUES"
        From
            tbl order by ST_TIME
    )
Where RDNG_DT = To_Date('10-JAN-23', 'dd-MON-yy')
Group By TAG, RDNG_DT, ST_TIME, END_TIME
Order By TAG, RDNG_DT, ST_TIME, END_TIME


TAG RDNG_DT   ST_TIME END_TIME TAG_VALUES
--- --------- ------- -------- ----------
RST 10-JAN-23 12:00   12:05            10 
RST 10-JAN-23 12:05   12:10            20
```